# perfect square special formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take the formula:
$$(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$$

for example: $$(x - 3)^2 = x^2 - (2x)(3) + 3^2$$
$$= x^2 - 6x + 9$$

But b = -3 in $(a - b)^2$ , which yields $$x^2  - (2x)(-3) + 3^2$$
$$= x^2 + 6x + 9$$
Shouldn't the formula be: $$(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2a\lvert b\rvert + b^2$$

Thanks

Comment: $b=+3$ in $(a-b)^2$, while $b=-3$ in $(a+b)^2$.

Comment: well $b-3\ne b+3$

Comment: For your second example, $b=-3$, the expression would be $(x + 3)^2 $.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics, where it has other meaning. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$), `\times` ($\times$) or ideally simple juxtaposition.

Answer (score 3):

No, it shouldn't! If b= -3 then $(a- b)^2= (a- (-3))^2= (a+ 3)^2=a^2+ 6x+ 9$, exactly what your formula gives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

$$(a + |b|)^2 = a^2 + 2a|b| + b^2$$

For $b >0,\ |b| = b$ hence

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

For $b < 0,\ |b| = -b$ hence

$$(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$$

Comment: In: $$(a - b)^2$$
Is this the same as: $$(+ a - b)^2$$
In other words a is positive and b is negative? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: I see where I was thinking incorrectly. I was taking the second part of the equation $$a^2 - 2ab + b^2$$
as a formula, where you just plug in the values from the first part, hence 'b' would be negative since it follows a negative sign. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the formula be: $$(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2a\lvert b\rvert + b^2$$

**No!** Let $a=1, b=-1$ then if
$(a-b)^2=a^2-2a|b|+b^2$
then
$$2^2=(1-(-1))^2=(a-b)^2=1-2\times1\times|-1|+(-1)^2=0.$$